# Apple ID two-factor authentication in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, two-factor-authentication

As of February 27, 2019, Apple forces developer accounts to use an extra security layer called Two-Factor Authentication.

When I try to login to my Apple Developer account through Visual Studio 2019, it seems 2FA is not supported; Visual Studio doesn't ask me for a security code after I enter my username/password.

Is 2FA supported in Visual Studio?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not supported as of now by Visual studio but since it is sort of an issue i expect they will address it soon!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visual Studio 2019 Preview 4.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin#--visual-studio-2019-preview-42-) supports two-factor auth for the Apple ID login

[image: TwoFactorAuth]

Comment: I don't think this works on Visual Studio for Mac. No dialog is appearing for me?